# Use apply() to assign value to new column

Tags: python, graphlab

I have a SArray called `word_count` in a `SFrame` called sf. Every row in the `word_count` SArray consists of a dict.
I have an array called `selected_words`
I am trying to loop through every column to see which of the words from "selected_words" appears in the column. If it appears i take the value and write it into a new column.
Here is an example for just one word ('great'):

```
selected_words = ['awesome ', 'great']
def word_count(row):
    if 'great' in row:
           sf['great']=row['great']
    else:
         abc="a" #nothing should happen
sf['word_count'].apply(word_count)

+-------------------------------+
|           word_count          |
+-------------------------------+
| {'and': 5, '6': 1, 'stink'... |
| {'and': 3, 'love': 1, 'it'... |
| {'and': 2, 'quilt': 1, 'it... |
| {'ingenious': 1, 'and': 3,... |
| {'and': 2, 'parents!!': 1,... |
| {'and': 2, 'this': 2, 'her... |
| {'shop': 1, 'noble': 1, 'i... |
| {'and': 2, 'all': 1, 'righ... |
| {'and': 1, 'help': 1, 'giv... |
| {'journal.': 1, 'nanny': 1... |
+-------------------------------+


print sf['great']
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ... ]
```

As far as I have understood, the same value(1) gets applied to every row, but i only need it in that row where the word 'great' was actually found.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that you are changing the full column sf['great'] after each call of the function word_count. Here's another approach :

```
def word_count(d):
    return d['great'] if 'great' in d else 0
```

and after that apply this function to the sf['word_count'] column :

```
sf['great'] = sf['word_count'].apply(word_count)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is also the fastest way to do an operation like this with a DataFrame.